# Android button for set as ringtone from my json mp3 URL link

Tags: android, json, set, ringtone

I have created 1 android application it is simple 2 buttons which is stream and download mp3 file from json URL .
The mp3 file downloaded  in my custom folder then I want to crate set as ringtone button it  can be picking file my downloaded custom folder and set as ring tone .
 please help

Comment: I created 1 button and used string path for offline downloaded file for setting ringtone but it is not working for me.

Comment: I want to create 1 button on my list view that select file from my every list particular uri file and click button and set ringtone.